# Have a use enter in how many rolls, then only output the sum of two dice on the last roll Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dice

The goal of this code is to create a web page that rolls a pair of dice when a button is clicked. The user is prompted to enter the number of times the dice should be rolled. These rolls will be thrown out (burned) and I will only use the last roll. The staring dice should change to the two dice that were rolled on the last roll.

The roll count should be between 1 and 100.  Any non-valid values entered should alert the user of the issue, notify them you are changing it, and change their entry to 50.

There should be a line that shows the total of the last roll.  On the initial run of the web page roll line should = 0, but after all the rolls it should show the total of just the last roll.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Dice Roller</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/icon.png" />

<script type="text/javascript">

    function diceRoll()
    {
        var dice1Num = parseInt((Math.random() * 6) + 1);     //create a random integer between 1 and 6
        var dice2Num = parseInt((Math.random() * 6) + 1);

        var numberRolls = document.rollNum.numRolls.value;



        if (numberRolls > 100 || numberRolls < 1)
        {
            numberRolls == 50;
            alert("The number of rolls entered is invalid. The number of rolls as been set to 50.");
        }
        for (var rollCount = 0; rollCount < numRolls; rollcount++;)
        {
            var diceSum = 0;
            diceSum = dice1Num + dice2Num;
        }

        var d1Image = document.getElementById("dice1Start");   //this attaches the image to the div, dice1.
        if (dice1Num == 1)
        {
            d1Image.src = "images/one.png"    //defines the path for the  attached images if the condtion is met (same for all similar lines, just different paths). This was also learned from stack overflow
        }
        else if (dice1Num == 2)
        {
            d1Image.src = "images/two.png"
        }
        else if (dice1Num == 3)
        {
            d1Image.src = "images/three.png"
        }
        else if (dice1Num == 4)
        {
            d1Image.src = "images/four.png"
        }
        else if (dice1Num == 5)
        {
            d1Image.src = "images/five.png"
        }
        else if (dice1Num == 6)
        {
            d1Image.src = "images/six.png"
        }



        var d2Image = document.getElementById("dice2Start");    //this  attaches the image to the div, dice2
        if (dice2Num == 1)
        {
            d2Image.src = "images/one.png"
        }
        else if (dice2Num == 2)
        {
            d2Image.src = "images/two.png"
        }
        else if (dice2Num == 3)
        {
            d2Image.src = "images/three.png"
        }
        else if (dice2Num == 4)
        {
            d2Image.src = "images/four.png"
        }
        else if (dice2Num == 5)
        {
            d2Image.src = "images/five.png"
        }
        else if (dice2Num == 6)
        {
            d2Image.src = "images/six.png"
        }

        alert(diceSum);
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
</p1>

<h1>Click the button to roll two dice!</h1>

<img id="dice1Start" src="images/pre-roll.png" alt="Dice with question    marks.">
<img id="dice2Start" src="images/pre-roll.png" alt="Dice with question  marks.">


<form name="rollNum">
    <p>How many rolls to burn? <input type="number" name="numRolls"></p>
    <p><input type="button" value="Roll!" name="btnSubmit" onClick="diceRoll()"></p>
</form>
<p>Last Roll =  </p>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the site as this code makes it. 
http://studentweb.cdm.depaul.edu/~fkreutze/assignment-6/assignment-6.html?numRolls=15

When I hit the button to call the function nothing happens as the starting dice don't change to the dice that were rolled. I've been stuck on this for some time now, so any help or constructive criticism is welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

The extra semicolon in this line is a syntax error.

`for (var rollCount = 0; rollCount < numRolls; rollcount++;)`

In the future bring up the javascript console in your browser, as this error appeared immediately.